# How to deal with Heteroskedasticity in a GAM model

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, gamma-distribution, mgcv

I am running a set of GAMs (Generalized Additive Models) to model a smoothed effect. I have verified all the other necessary checks of my GAMs for the basis functions, etc. However, I find persistent issues with the heteroskedasticity of the model. My code (in r, using the `mgcv` package, to be specific) is the following:

```r
library(mgcv)
model1 <- gam(outcome ~ factor +
                          s(var1, k = 50) + 
                          var2 + var3, data = data, method = "RELM")
```

where "outcome" is a continuous variable with a range from 0 to 1.

And my `gam.check()` of model1 produces the following:

[image: check1]
[image: check2]
[image: check3]
[image: check4]

This seems to me to be a clear case of heteroskedasticity, meaning that I cannot use a Gaussian distribution for this model. However, I do not understand how to handle this problem. I have seen it suggested (Wood, 2011; etc.) that one can simply change the `family` argument to a distribution that better reflects the distribution. However this does not appear to help.

For example, I know that var1 is time-based, which many model with a Gamma distribution. However, switching to a Gamma distribution doesn't fix the problem. If I use a Gamma distribution with the following code:

```r
model2 <- gam(outcome+0.0000000000001 ~ factor +
              s(var1, k = 50) + var2 + var3, data = data, 
              method = "RELM", family=Gamma(link="log")))
```

(I add the tiny value to "outcome" because 0's cannot be modelled with log)

I still get problems with the distribution of residuals:

[image: check5]
[image: check6]

And the same for logit, which I have also seen suggested (but I think makes little sense given the outcome variable):

```r
model3 <- gam(outcome ~ factor + s(var1, k = 50) + var2 + var3, 
              data = data, method = "RELM", 
              family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

[image: check7]
[image: check8]

For the Logit version, the histogram of residuals looks the most normal, but the QQplot still deviates. And I still am suspect of logit for this outcome variable.

My questions are therefore the following:

1. Is the heteroskedasticity I find here a problem? Or am I overstating it?
2. If it is problematic for a gaussian distribution, how can I solve this? Is there another distribution I can use that fits the model well?
3. Do I need to transform the outcome variable in some way? Do I need to use a link function? The outcome variable is heavily left skewed, with most of the observations at the very tope of the scale, but it is continuous.
4. Is there a way to preserve this model but use heteroskedastic standard errors? Or is this not an option with GAMs? I saw this suggested with r's `gamlss` package, but I do not think it applied to this case.

**Note:** I ask these questions here because I think it is more of a statistical question than a true coding question.

**UPDATE**:

Following Roland's comments, I tried using `ocat` as the family, with the following code:

```
model3 <- gam(outcome ~ factor + s(var1, k = 50) + var2 + var3, 
              data = data, method = "RELM", 
              family = ocat(R = 11))
```

and I got this as a result:

[image: check9]
[image: check10]
[image: check11]
[image: check12]

I am wondering how to interpret these. The QQplot fits nearly perfectly, except for the gap in the middle of the quantiles, and the same goes for the histogram of residuals. I assume these gaps are a function of the process for handling ordered categorical data. Can anyone explain why this emerges? And does this show an "okay" model fit?

Finally, is ordered categorical legitimate when the categories are from a numerical scale with theoretically equidistant points? I see this as legitimate, but does it change any assumptions/the nature of the GAM model?

Comment: Try family beta-binomial; glmmTMB(...,family = betabinomial). It's a glm instead of a gam, but maybe you don't need a gam yet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In this case, I know I need to use a GAM as it's the industry standard for this research question. Could you explain what assumptions would be made using the beta-binomial family? Is it just to match this type of distribution?

Comment: You can't model a continuous variable bounded at 0 and 1 with `family = binomial()` unless you specify the sample total counts via weights. Really these models are for counts from a total count and you need to inform it of that total count. I doubt it is the case that you have a truly continuous response given the banding in the response data shown in the diagnostic plot, but if it is truly continuous then you can try `family = betar()` but this is going to adjust any 0 and 1 values a little such that they are within the interval 0-1 not on the boundary.

Comment: Also, you should read up on generalized linear models to learn more about this class of models. The GAM is just a fancy GLM, You need to understand why we choose different random components for different kinds of response, and the role of the link function. The random component `family` usually suggests itself just by thinking about the range of values your response can take. This is clearly not Gaussian, which has support on the full number line, both positive and negative, and its not Gamma as it has support on the set of positive real values. Neither of which matches your data

Comment: Thank you for the input @GavinSimpson. You were correct, the data is not truly continuous, in that I have rescaled ordinal categories on a 10-point scale to a numerical scale. Would a different distribution be preferable based on this? I have seen other options for family dealing with unordered categories, but this is not the case here, I would think.

Comment: Also, could you suggest any readings specific to the link function? I understand the association between GLM and GAM (the latte is just advisable in this case) but the link function is certainly a gap for me

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You should probably ask how you should analyze ordinal data with a GAM. `help("ocat")` might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Roland I have updated my question with an attempt at using ocat. I am now trying to interpret the results and assess if this is a legitimate model fit. Would you please be able to comment on these results?